# sorting a list of several list

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a list of several list. for example in `index[1]` I have a list `[name, number1, number2]`, I want sort this list by `number1` and after that `number2`
Is this possible? [[name,20,10], [name,3,20], [name,5,40]]
I want change to: [[name,20,10], [name,5,40], [name,3,20]]

```
public class WriteToFile {
Game game= new Game();
GUI gui= new GUI();
RandomAccessFile raf= null;
Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
List gameInfoList= new ArrayList();

 protected void fillList(){
  gameInfoList.add(0,askName());
     gameInfoList.add(1,game.flag);
     gameInfoList.add(gui.different/1000);
     try {

         raf= new RandomAccessFile("D://Game.txt","rw");

     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
     try {

         raf.seek(raf.length());
         raf.writeUTF(String.valueOf(gameInfoList));
         raf.writeUTF("\r\n");
     } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
     try {
         raf.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }
 }

protected String askName() {
    System.out.println(" Please Insert Your Name:");
    String userName=scanner.next();
    return userName;

}

}

public class MaxPoint implements Comparable {
int max;

public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return 0;
}
WriteToFile writeToFile= new WriteToFile();
RandomAccessFile raf= null;
List lineList= new ArrayList();
Iterator it= lineList.iterator();
protected void findMax(){
    try {
        raf= new RandomAccessFile("D://Game.txt","r") ;
        for(int i = 0;raf.readLine()!=null;i++){
            lineList.add(i, raf.readLine());
 }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`
```

Comment: What is the type of your list of list?

Comment: [[string,int.int],...]

Comment: By List, do you mean array? Or List of Object? Please share some code to clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
List<List<Object>> ll = // ...
Collections.sort(ll, new Comparator<List<Object>>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(List<Object> l1, List<Object> l2) {
        int n1 = (Integer) l1.get(1);
        int n2 = (Integer) l2.get(1);
        return n2 - n1;   // descending order
    }
});
```